# Get unique values from pandas series of lists

Tags: python, pandas, set, unique, pie-chart

I have a column in DataFrame containing list of categories. For example:

```
0                                                    [Pizza]
1                                 [Mexican, Bars, Nightlife]
2                                  [American, New, Barbeque]
3                                                     [Thai]
4          [Desserts, Asian, Fusion, Mexican, Hawaiian, F...
6                                           [Thai, Barbeque]
7                           [Asian, Fusion, Korean, Mexican]
8          [Barbeque, Bars, Pubs, American, Traditional, ...
9                       [Diners, Burgers, Breakfast, Brunch]
11                                [Pakistani, Halal, Indian]
```

I am attempting to do two things:

1) Get unique categories - My approach is have a empty set, iterate through series and append each list.

my code:

```
unique_categories = {'Pizza'}
for lst in restaurant_review_df['categories_arr']:
    unique_categories = unique_categories | set(lst)
```

This give me a set of unique categories contained in all the lists in the column.

2) Generate pie plot of category counts and each restaurant can belong to multiple categories. For example: restaurant 11 belongs to Pakistani, Indian and Halal categories. My approach is again iterate through categories and one more iteration through series to get counts.

Are there simpler or elegant ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with the data you want.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Update using pandas 0.25.0+ with `explode`

```
df['category'].explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Barbeque       3
Mexican        3
Fusion         2
Thai           2
American       2
Bars           2
Asian          2
Hawaiian       1
New            1
Brunch         1
Pizza          1
Traditional    1
Pubs           1
Korean         1
Pakistani      1
Burgers        1
Diners         1
Indian         1
Desserts       1
Halal          1
Nightlife      1
Breakfast      1
Name: Places, dtype: int64
```

And with plotting:

```
df['category'].explode().value_counts().plot.pie(figsize=(8,8))
```

Output:

[image]

---

For older verions of pandas before 0.25.0
Try:

```
df['category'].apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Mexican        3
Barbeque       3
Thai           2
Fusion         2
American       2
Bars           2
Asian          2
Pubs           1
Burgers        1
Traditional    1
Brunch         1
Indian         1
Korean         1
Halal          1
Pakistani      1
Hawaiian       1
Diners         1
Pizza          1
Nightlife      1
New            1
Desserts       1
Breakfast      1
dtype: int64
```

With plotting:

```
df['category'].apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts().plot.pie()
```

Output:
[image]

Per @coldspeed's comments

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Counter(chain(*df['category'])), orient='index').sort_values(0, ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
Barbeque     3
Mexican      3
Bars         2
American     2
Thai         2
Asian        2
Fusion       2
Pizza        1
Diners       1
Halal        1
Pakistani    1
Brunch       1
Breakfast    1
Burgers      1
Hawaiian     1
Traditional  1
Pubs         1
Korean       1
Desserts     1
New          1
Nightlife    1
Indian       1
```

Comment: `df['category'].apply(pd.Series)` nooo!! You should consider Counter + itertools.chain instead.

Comment: @coldspeed Yes, for speed but if you are doing quick analysis, I go with easiest and is readable atleast for me.

Comment: I would probably do both, instead of doing one and hoping OP can figure out the other. Anyway, this is going to be "quick" for data that is a few thousand rows or less.