# pandas.Series.explode throws AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to [count the number of unique values in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813384/11568368) using [pandas.Series.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode)
as I'm not interested in exploding the entire dataframe. 
The dataframe column I'm trying to explode looks like

```
df["lists"].head()

0    [cl5, bn6, sp1]  
1    [cl5, bn6, sp1]  
2    [cl5, bn6, sp1]  
3         [bn6, sp1]  
4         [bn6, sp1]  
Name: lists, dtype: object
```

I tried `df.lists.explode().value_counts()` which throws an ***AttributeError***: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'.
The same error is observed while [exploding the entire dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with `df.explode('lists')`. I cannot see if it been deprecated so I'm not sure what's wrong when the source examples don't work either.

Comment: ```df.to_frame().explode('lists')``` will do

Comment: What is the version of Pandas package that you are using? in case of multiple environments, and if you are not sure, just print `pandas.__version__` after importing pandas in your python code. Could you please edit your question and add that information to your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Pandas official documentation about Series.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), this function is

> New in version 0.25.0.

I think your problem might be because of an older package version. Updating your pandas package might resolve your issue.